# Is it possible to stop rendering filters for some categories in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation, list.phtml

How can I prevent/stop rendering layered navigation (filters) for some categories in product list page in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set from category page `is anchor to No`.

Go to

> Product -> Categories

Click on your category,

```
Display settings 
Set Anchor to No.
```

[image]

Clear Cache.

Comment: yes, working @Rakesh :) currently am not able to accept your answer after 7 mins Will accept it.

Comment: Ok sure, You can set it for any category from backend. If required enable for specific category in future just set Is Anchor to Yes and clear cache.

Comment: can we able to remove default "category filter" ? means what ever filters I want I can make them at the time of attribute creation but here I did not create category filter.I dont want that.How can I remove ?

Comment: you have to disable specific code from template file for category.

Comment: If you already know that file let me know the path or else I will check :)

Comment: sorry i am not know file but you have to debug for that file using template path hint and you have set condition for only remove for is anchor with no.

Comment: You can add new question so any user know about that issue post answer.

Comment: sure, Will ask that as a new question :)

Comment: In my default magento no category are display after remove layered navigaiton.

Comment: ohh ok, Then will check it in my theme level

Comment: you can close this question now after mark as accetped

Comment: able to accept it now

Answer (score 1):

You can set it from **Admin**

> Product >> Categories >> Display Settings >> Anchor (**SET NO**)